# Java SimpleDateFormat Differing Behaviour Between Systems

Tags: java, parsing, simpledateformat

We are working on a collaborative project utilising a database, and the Java interface for this database uses SimpleDateFormat to convert the string data into a Date object. For most of us, this works fine, but a couple of our contributors are getting a ParseException.

We've managed to trace the problem down to the fact that for whatever reason, on these user's systems, the SimpleDateFormat is treating "MMM" and "EEE" as an expectation of the full month/day name in English. However all the documentation we can find says that these are expecting the shortened 3 letter versions, and for most of us this is how it behaves.

For example, the database will have the string "Tue Feb 01 00:00:00 AEDT 2022". For most of us, this parses fine. However, some of us get a ParseException, and if those people edit the database to store "Tuesday February 01 00:00:00 AEDT 2022", it works for them but fails for the rest of us.

The formatting string is "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy". We think it could be related to which specific JDK each of us is using but surely there wouldn't be any changes like that between them that would cause a totally different interpretation of the same format string, right?

Comment: I highly recommend using the Date & Time API introduced with Java 8 instead of the old classes. They have a specification (JSR-354) and will behave identically, independent of the Java vendor and operating system.

Comment: I think storing a `String` with names of months and days of week in a shared database appears somehow like an antipattern. Those names as well as the abbreviation of the time zone depend on the configuration of the system. Why don't you store epoch millis, for example? But apart from that, it's quite interesting that *some systems* treat `EEE` as the full name of the day of week while others don't and resolve it to the abbreviated name.

Comment: @deHaar to be fair, our "database" is a CSV file. But we've done this out of convenience - my problem is the second part of your comment, how and most importantly why would this behaviour differ between systems?

Comment: @McPringle we'll look into that, thanks

Comment: To be honest: It shouldn't differ between systems. It is interesting that it does, but I don't know how much time it would take to find out the reason if possible at all. Definitely look into `java.time` and a way to prevent these problems would be to store a timestamp in a format that is independent from language, time zone, offsets and stuff that differs all over the world.

Comment: This will be due to `Locale` differences between the respective installations. You need to ensure that if you expect a specific date format, *the application* uses the appropriate `Locale`. Not just the default. And I echo @deHaar's comment. The database has several date/time/timestamp datatypes built in. Use them.

Comment: @deHaar yeah in future we'll do that

Comment: @user207421 this is what we thought at first too, but why would the locale change the meaning of "MMM" and "EEE". I can see how locale would change from expecting Monday to Montag or whatever, but why would it cause a different interpretation of the format string? That definitely doesn't make sense

Comment: @goshacaracal Certainly it makes sense, if it is customary in a given `Locale` to use different numbers of letters for a day or month name instead of what we're used to. That's exactly what it's for.

Comment: To store dates and times as strings in a CSV file use [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). It’s language neutral and both machine and human readable. As a bonus java.time, the modern Java date and time API mentioned in other comments, has very good support for ISO 8601.

Comment: I tried all available locales in my Oracle JDK 11 and could not reproduce your described behaviour.

Comment: @user207421 no that still makes no sense. There is no locale where the short name for Monday is Monday and the long name is Mon.

Comment: @OleV.V. yes, as I suspected, this has nothing to do with locales

Comment: @user207421 is basically correct. There are locales where the short name for September is `Sep` and others where it is `Sept` or `Sept.` (with a dot). Can we rule out a locale where the short name is `September`? No way. It’s *not the only*  explanation, but it *is a possible* explanation.

Comment: On the installations with the unexpected behaviour: (1) Which locale is used? (2) What is the value of the system property `java.locale.providers`? (3) What is the *operating system*’s default locale?